# Setting field tab stops in Word 2010 for pdf conversion

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion

When converting a Word 2010 docx to pdf, the tab stops at all hyperlinks in the pdf file. 
What I am looking to do is have the tab stop at the form fields only (not hyperlinks), in the converted pdf file.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat will stop at hyperlinks, as the user may want to select them.  You can prevent this by right clicking the hyperlinks in the Word document (before conversion to PDF) and select "remove hyperlink"  The hyperlinks will no longer be selectable via tabbing.  If you want the text for the hyperlinks to remain blue, you will have to manually change the font color.